# Grouping array based on special character count

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'd like to write a program that takes an array of strings and returns an object that groups those strings into arrays based on the number of non-alphanumeric characters in them.

Input

```
var list= ['1','1.2','1.2.3','1.23.4','1.4','11','33.44.55.66.99','ab.cd.ed.df'];
```

Output

```
var output = {
  count4:['33.44.55.66.99'],
  count3:['ab.cd.ed.df'],
  count2:['1.2.3','1.23.4'],
  count1:['1.2','1.4'],
  count0:['1','11']
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way, it will work for you

```js
var list = ['1', '1.2', '1.2.3', '1.23.4', '1.4', '11', '33.44.55.66.99', 'ab.cd.ed.df'];
var output = {}

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    let count = list[i].split('.').length - 1;

    if (!output[`count${count}`]) {
        output[`count${count}`] = []
    }

    output[`count${count}`].push(list[i])  

}
var ordered = {};
Object.keys(output).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  ordered[key] = output[key];
});

console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: for Count4 and count3 order missing , Narendra Chouhan

Comment: i have edited my answer please check it @SamJay , please upvote the answer if its correct

Comment: sure , i will do

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple reduce.

```js
const list = ['1','1.2','1.2.3','1.23.4','1.4','11','33.44.55.66.99','ab.cd.ed.df'];
const obj = list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const dots = cur.split('.').length - 1
    const key = `count${dots}`
    return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: [...(acc[key]||[]), cur].sort()
    }
}, {});
console.log (obj)
```

Comment: thank you Moritz Roessler, is it possible get sequence order array like   count0,count1,count2,count3,count4 ...etc.

Comment: for  grouping its working fine but Count4 and count3 order missing. i need oder like count1 ,count2,count3 and count4(asc) or count4 ,count3 ,count2 and count(desc) oder

Comment: @SamJay Just add a `.sort()` after the array. I updated the answer

Comment: i saw your output ,sort() is not working .